# How do I find similarity between 2 images in pixels using Java

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, android-camera2

I have a method that compares the pixels inside each image, it works for me when I use the same images but not when I'm using 2 images with large area of similarity.

I've tried altering my code and the way I look for the similar pixels but no luck. I'm finding some similar pixels but not the right ones.

After I find an equal pixel, I check if the next pixel in each image equals too and it doesn't seem to find the similar regions.
Below you can see the code I use to compare pixels.

```
private boolean comparePixels(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2, int x, int x2, int y, int y2) {
    int pixel = bitmap1.getPixel(x,y);
    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

    int pixel2 = bitmap2.getPixel(x2,y2);
    int redValue2 = Color.red(pixel2);
    int blueValue2 = Color.blue(pixel2);
    int greenValue2 = Color.green(pixel2);

    int haversine = Math.abs(redValue2 - redValue) + Math.abs(blueValue2 - blueValue) + Math.abs(greenValue2 - greenValue);
    return haversine <= 10;
}
```

I expect to find the similarity between the images and get the equal regions in each image.

I want to note that I've searched in plenty of posts in stackoverflow and many other sites and didn't manage to find anything that helped me.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: you probably want to iterate through pixels on both images checking how similar they are

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko That's what I do, I iterate through the pixels in both images and I don't get an area of equal pixels only equality of spread pixels inside the images that doesn't seem right because the area of similarity is large

Comment: Du both of your Bitemaps have the exact same dimensions?

Comment: You should add the code you use for traversing the image as well, the error lies most likely there.

Comment: Both Bitmaps have the same dimensions. and it gives the same result even from iterating through each pixel in each image and comparing them. @TA